# How to see a more descriptive error message for Hadoop streaming?

Tags: hadoop, streaming

I'm using the `Hadoop` streaming interface via `hadoop-streaming-1.0.3.16.jar`.

My map task fails with this message:

```
ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: <task id>
```

I get no other diagnostics.

I'm running the map-reduce streaming task with these options:

- file  -mapper
- file  -reducer
- input /user/ME/INPUT_FILE
- output /user/ME/OUTPUT_FILE

How do I get better (some!) diagnostics on why the map task failed?

Comment: Can you see the output of STDOUT in Hue?

Comment: Please update the question with the full command you are using.